# chromedp getting invalid CSRF token errors; Puppeteer and the browser are OK

Tags: go, gorilla, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm using chromedp to test my Go-based website. While I've managed to do basic login tests with it, I'm getting CSRF errors when I try to sign out of an account that I've just logged in as.

Here's the test function that's getting the CSRF error and its main helper. `httpServerURL` is the base URL of either the live webserver running or an `httptest.Server.URL` (I get the same CSRF error either way):

```golang
func TestSignupDuplicate(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    ctx, cancel = chromedp.NewContext(ctx) //   chromedp.WithDebugf(log.Printf),

    defer cancel()

    email := "doubly.headless@example.com"
    password := "asdfasdf"

    signUpWithContext(ctx, t, email, password)

    defer func() {
        if err := userManager.DeleteByEmail(email); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    var postSignoutClickLocationGot string
    postSignoutClickLocationExpected := httpServerURL + "/"
    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Click("//button[@class='sign-out-form__button']"),
        chromedp.Sleep(800*time.Millisecond),
        chromedp.Location(&postSignoutClickLocationGot),
    ); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    if postSignoutClickLocationGot != postSignoutClickLocationExpected {
        t.Logf("Expected to be redirected to <%s> after signing out, but was here instead: <%s>",
            postSignoutClickLocationExpected,
            postSignoutClickLocationGot,
        )
    }

    var location string
    var html string
    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        //chromedp.WaitReady("//footer"),
        chromedp.Location(&location),
        chromedp.InnerHTML("/html", &html),
    ); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Had trouble getting debug information: %s", err)
    }

    log.Println(location)
    log.Println(html)

    signUpWithContext(ctx, t, email, password)

    expectedAlertHeading := "E-mail address already in use"
    var gotAlertHeading string

    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Text("//*[@class='alert__heading']", &gotAlertHeading),
    ); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("couldn’t get alert heading: %s", err)
    }

    if expectedAlertHeading != gotAlertHeading {
        t.Fatalf("Unexpected alert heading. Want: «%s». Got: «%s»", expectedAlertHeading, gotAlertHeading)
    }
}

func signUpWithContext(ctx context.Context, t *testing.T, email, password string) {
    t.Helper()

    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate(httpServerURL+"/signup/"),
        chromedp.WaitVisible("#email", chromedp.ByID),
        chromedp.SendKeys("#email", email, chromedp.ByID),
        chromedp.SendKeys("#password", password, chromedp.ByID),
        chromedp.Submit("//button[@type='submit']"),
    ); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

And here's the output of that:

```
Running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go test -timeout 30s example.com/webdictions -run ^(TestSignupDuplicate)$

2019/07/05 15:26:02 http://127.0.0.1:53464/signout/
2019/07/05 15:26:02 <head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">Forbidden - CSRF token invalid
</pre></body>
--- FAIL: TestSignupDuplicate (3.01s)
    /Users/comatoast/Projects/predictionsweb/main_test.go:150: Expected to be redirected to <http://127.0.0.1:53464/> after signing out, but was here instead: <http://127.0.0.1:53464/signout/>
    /Users/comatoast/Projects/predictionsweb/main_test.go:177: couldn’t get alert heading: context deadline exceeded
FAIL
FAIL    example.com/webdictions 3.073s
```

Oddly enough, a Puppeteer program doesn't error out like this. At its end I don't get any screenshots of CSRF errors, regardless of whether the user already has an account before I start the test:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const opts = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        deviceScaleFactor: 2,
    }
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({defaultViewport: opts});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.localhost:3000/');
    await page.click("a[href='/signup/']");
    await page.type('#email', "headless.javascript@example.com");
    await page.type('#password', 'asdfasdf');
    await page.click('[type="submit"]');
    await page.screenshot({path: '1. should be the dashboard after signup.png'});

    await page.click('.sign-out-form__button');
    await page.screenshot({path: '2. should be slash.png'});

    await page.click('a[href="/signup/"]')
    await page.screenshot({path: '3. signup again.png'});

    await page.type('#email', "headless.javascript@example.com");
    await page.type('#password', 'asdfasdf');
    await page.click('[type="submit"]');

    await page.screenshot({path: '4. after second identical signup attempt.png'});

//    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Likewise, when I try to sign up for the same account twice in either Safari or Chrome, I get a normal "this e-mail address is already in use" error, not a CSRF error. What, if anything, am I doing incorrectly via chromedp?

Comment: I would have tagged this post "chromedp", but I don't have enough rep to do so yet. The tag would apply to posts about using <https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, on the second access of the "Sign up" page, I had a one-button "Sign out" form that `chromedp.Submit("//button[@type='submit']")` was clicking on. Changing the path to an unambiguous `chromedp.Submit("//form[@action='/signup/']//button[@type='submit']")` in `signUpWithContext` fixed my problem of clicking on the submit button of the wrong form.